# MS Word styleref field string replace

Tags: ms-word, field

Is there a way to apply an automatic string replace on the result of a styleref field?

My current styleref:

```
{STYLEREF  style1  \* MERGEFORMAT}
```

If it resulted in: **foo_bar**, I'd like to see: **foo-bar**

I saw the formula type of field, but it has no string replace function.

I am using Microsoft Word 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only modify what a `STYLEREF` field displays by modifying the text in the document to which the `STYLEREF` field refers.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like this.